# jquery ui sortable with angularjs, how to prevent horizontal drag and drop? axis:y not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui sortable with angularjs
I am doing this:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
            start: function(e, ui) {
                $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
            },
            update: function(e, ui) {
                $(this).removeAttr('data-previndex');
            },
            receive: function(e, ui) {
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var val = ui.item.attr("val");
                $("#list"+val+" li").each(function(i, el){
                    $scope.updateTop(val,el.id,i);
                });
                $("#list"+val+"sub li").each(function(i, el){
                    $scope.updateBottom(val,el.id);
                });
            },
            connectWith: ".group",
            axis: 'y',
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
            helper: "clone",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
        };
```

As you can see I have given axis:y so it should allow drag and drop vertically only but horizontal drag and drop also works. I don't need horizontal drag and drop. Is there any other option to solve this issue?
Html looks like:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 sortable">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <td ng-repeat="amount_info in amount_data" valign="top" width="300">
                    <!--sort list-->
                    <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" id="list{{amount_info.amount}}" class="group so_list{{amount_info.amount}}" ng-model="amount_info.sortList" >
                        <li ng-mouseup="mouseUp(sortItem.ProductId,amount_info.amount)" amount="{{amount_info.amount}}" ng-repeat="sortItem in amount_info.sortList track by $index" ProductId="{{sortItem.ProductId}}" id="prod_{{sortItem.ProductId}}">
                        <div id="tc_prod">
                                {{sortItem.Product}} [{{sortItem.ProductId}}] 
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="listdivide"></div>
                    <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" id="list{{amount_info.amount}}sub" class="group so_list{{amount_info.amount}}"  ng-model="amount_info.nonSortList" >
                        <li  ng-repeat="nonsortItem in amount_info.nonSortList track by $index" productId="{{nonsortItem.ProductId}}" id="prod_{{nonsortItem.ProductId}}" amount="{{amount_info.amount}}">
                            {{nonsortItem.Product}} [{{nonsortItem.ProductId}}]
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each table td has a list in ul. items from one td should not be dragged to another td. But not it is possible. Axis:y is given but no effect. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding the following code.

beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        if($(ui.helper).parent().attr('class') != $(ui.placeholder).parent().attr('class')){
            return false;
        }
    },

where each ul should have separate class and check a condition to see if the sender and receiver's classes are same, then allow otherwise return false.

Answer (score 1):

axis y should work, here is the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjmBLw)

In this i have used

```
axis:'y'
```

and also the same config options as u have given

Comment: I have multiple table columns. In each one I have ul li list. Actually I need drag and drop only within each td. but it is draggable from one td to another. Axis y not working in my case.

Comment: i think then you will have to change the structure of your table as ui sortable works on the elements and in a table elements are rendered row wise not column wise.

Comment: my td contains list. I have many td element like that. I have updated my question with html. Can u have a look in html and let me know if it is something that jquery ui sortable supports?

Comment: Oh, then you can use the "items" property in sortable options, bascially create provide each list with a diffrent sortable option object with all the properties common except for the items property which will have a unique selector for each list which will solve yoru problem i guess

Comment: Thank you, will look into it.

Comment: no problem, just let me know if you are still stuck

Comment: Thank you, I tried by using different sortable option object as you suggested then the horizontal drag and drop is not possible. But now I am not able to drag from top list to bottom list and vice versa. Troubleshooting it now. pls share your suggestions if any.

Comment: basically provide a unique class to every list, for eaxmple for list 1 provide every td a class say "list1" and when you provide sortable options to that list, giver the items selector as ".lsit1", i think that should work can you share any fiddle or plunker so that i can debug and let u know the solution

Comment: Thanks, I had converted structure to div based. Tried as you said but no luck plunker created https://plnkr.co/edit/nS3hHQNUovzoIxhSbWon?p=catalogue. Could you have a look?

Comment: yeah sure i will look into it

Comment: there are many files to include etc. In the new plunker I have given the html structure and the initialization of sortableoptions object. Could you have a look and tell me if anything to be modified in this? https://plnkr.co/edit/gF6eWDaAF0ePudQngRQo?p=catalogue

Comment: try item selector as this  items: ".li"+obj.amount,

Comment: I had tried it but didn't work. anyway thank you for your time. Solved the issue by another method. I have posted it as answer.